# Fit Bounds on Markers Doesn't Work Properly For Next Clicks on Multi Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can you please take a look at [this link](http://iomhumanitarian.atwebpages.com/map2.html) and let me know what I am doing wrong which the `map.fitBounds(bounds);` is just functioning correctly for First click option( doesn't really matter which one, it just do the zoom extends on first click but for the rest doesn't change the extend).

Here is also my code for one of buttons:

```
$( "#reg3" ).click(function() {
removeMarkers();
 $.ajax({
    // type: "POST",
    url: 'reg7_R1.json.txt',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ 
      locations.length = 0;
       for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude,data.markers[p].longitude),
      map: map,
      title:"marker "+p
    });
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    locations.push(marker);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
    },
    error: function (xhr,status,errorStr) {
      alert("status="+status+", error="+errorStr);
    }
  }); 
});
```

I almost repeated this for all three buttons

Comment: What does removeMarkers do?  Does it clear out the existing bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear out the global bounds object when you remove the markers (or when you do a new AJAX request.

```
 function removeMarkers() {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        if(locations[i])
             locations[i].setMap(null)
    }
}
```